# Adding en element in typescript by invoking a different parameterized method

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a method which adds an element to my array.
I am new in typescript and unable to find help as what will go in addNewProduct function. I am getting one push function as help. But when coded it shows "not applicable on type {}"

```
class ProductsComponent {

 title = 'Products List';

 products: any[] = [
   {
     'name': 'a',
     'quantity': 20
   },
   {
     'name': 'b',
     'quantity': 200
   }
 ];

constructor(){
  //print the current Product Array
  this.addNewProduct('c', 50 );
  // print the new Array
}
 addNewProduct(name: string, quantity: number) {
   // code
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with something like:

```
class AppComponent {

 title = 'Products List';

 products = [
   {
     'name': 'a',
     'quantity': 20
   },
   {
     'name': 'b',
     'quantity': 200
   }
 ];

constructor(){
  //print the current Product Array
  this.addNewProduct('c', 50 );
  // print the new Array
}
 addNewProduct(name: string, quantity: number) {
   // code
     this.products.push({name: name,quantity : quantity}); //< -- HERE ADD TO YOUR ARRAY PROP (products) A NEW OBJECT WITH PROPERTIES SETTED WITH ARGUMENT PARAMETERS
 }

}
```

`BECAREFULLY` .. if it gives to you an error like you said (`property 'push' does not exist on type {}`) ... it is because you're tryng to use push method on an object ..

so check your products array .. maybe it's NOT an array..

so maybe it's like:

```
products = { \\< -- double check here if you use [ or {
   {
     'name': 'a',
     'quantity': 20
   },
   {
     'name': 'b',
     'quantity': 200
   }
 }; // < -- and here again if you use ] or }
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Yes! It throws error "property 'push' does not exist on type {}"

Comment: it's not possbile .. the only reason it can happen is because you products IS NOT AN ARRAY BUT IT IS A OBJECT ..  .. so double check it .. maybe you've write  products = {
   {
     'name': 'a',
     'quantity': 20
   },
   {
     'name': 'b',
     'quantity': 200
   }
 };

Comment: Then how can I add one more element to this products object using addNewProduct function

Comment: it looks strange ..  but if you have to to try ... this.products = {  ... this.products, {name: name , quantity : quantity} }

Comment: I am using this code in a cutsom products component. products.component.html displays an initial set of products. There an input form will be available to add a new product. On clicking submit, the display should get updated with the new product. So, I am trying to invoke addNewProduct(name, quantity) to add new product in the array/object. But when I declare it as products={{}, {}}, it throws error. And push does not work on products=[{}, {}]. Any suggestions?? Constraint: can use only product.component.ts and product.component.html. Rest all app.component.*  and app.module.ts is standard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187850/discussion-between-federico-scamuzzi-and-shubham-verma).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Javascript example, which will also work using Typescript.
The example uses **Object Literal Property Value Shorthand** to create an object from the arguments and push it to your array.

This shorthand notation consists of omitting the value when both the key and the value have the same name:

```
const value = 'hello';
const obj = { value: value }
```

is the same as:

```
const value = 'hello';
const obj = { value }
```

and will result in:

```
{ value: 'hello' }
```

Here is the example for push:

```js
class ProductsComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.products = [{
      name: 'a',
      quantity: 20
    },
    {
      name: 'b',
      quantity: 200
    }];

    this.addNewProduct('c', 50 );
  }

  addNewProduct(name, quantity) {
    this.products.push({ name, quantity });
  }
}

const comp = new ProductsComponent();
console.log(comp.products);
```